# vertical align a div in middle of li elements

Tags: html, css, html-lists, vertical-alignment

I am lost and confusing `div`, `li` and `ul`. I can't vertically align the word EN in the middle of the form input.

Here is the demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/z9qjcv2k/

I tried with `height` and `line-height` which should have the same height and I can't get it to work.

Thanks all.

HTML:

```
<div class='line'>
  <div class='content_line'>
    <ul class='alignes'>
      <li>
        <div class='menu'>
        <ul class='menu'>
            <li class='menu'><a href='index.php?langue=en'>EN</a></li>
        </ul>
        </div>
       </li>
       <li><input type=text name=mots size=50 placeholder='Search...'></li>
       </ul>
 </div>
```

CSS:

```
*{
  margin:0;
}

.line{
height:100px;
background-color:#1b1b1b;
text-align:center;
border-top:1px solid #444444;
border-bottom:1px solid #444444;
padding-left:5%;
}

.alignes ul{


list-style-type:none;
}


.alignes li{
  display: inline;
    height: 233px;
    line-height: 233px;
color:#aaa8a9;
position:relative;
top:20px;
  height: 233px;
    line-height: 233:px;


}

.content_line{
padding-left:15%;
}








.menu{
display:inline important!;
float:left;


}

.menu ul {
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 list-style-type:none;
 text-align:center;
 }
.menu li {
 float:left;
 margin:auto;
 padding:0;
line-height:10px;
height:10px;
}
.menu li a {
 display:block;
 width:100px;
 color:red;
line-height:233px;
height:233px;
 text-decoration:none;
 padding:5px;
 }
.menu li a:hover {
 color:#FFD700;
 }  
.menu ul li ul {
 display:none;
 }

.menu ul li:hover ul {
 display:block;
 }
.menu li:hover ul li {
 float:none;
 }
.menu li ul {
 position:absolute;
 }
```

Comment: Your question is very unclear, please add more details and what the desired result is

Answer (score 0):

redefine .menu class float

```
  .menu {
   .....
   float: none;
  }
```

and set a proper padding to .menu li a

```
.menu li a {
   padding 2px;
}
```